# Tensorflow Quickstart Tutorial example - where do we say which column is what?

Tags: tensorflow, target, feature-selection

I'm slowly training myself on Tensorflow, following the Get Started section on Tensorflow.org. So far so good.

I have one question regarding the Iris data set example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator

When it comes to that section:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator#construct_a_deep_neural_network_classifier

It is not entirely clear to me when/where do we tell the system which columns are features and which column is the target value.

The only thing i see is that when we load the dataset, we tell the system the target is in integer format and the features are in float32. But what if my data is all integer or all float32 ? How can I tell the system that, for example, first 5 columns are features, and target is in last column. Or is it implied that first columns are always features and last column can only be the target ?

Answer (score 0):

The statement 'feature_columns=feature_columns' when defining the DNNClassifier says which columns are to be considered a part of the data, and the input function says what are inputs and what are labels.

Comment: thanks, i get it now. (sorry can't upvote your answer, not enough credit yet)